# Регулярное выражение js 2 символа

Tags: javascript

Возник вопрос как написать на js регулярное выражение ( с ними оч слаб )
в общем есть строки
/ru/main/page
/en/main/page
а так же могут быть просто
/main/page

нужно чтобы регуляркой выделяло именно ru или en ( не обязательно они могут быть ( могут быть и fr de sp и тд )
написал такую конструкцию

```
/[a-z][a-z]\//i
```

но оно работает только если уже есть вначале /ru или что то ещё 
если же нет то оно делает неправильную ссылку для меня
помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: ну вот пример
ссылка /ru/main/index
если я оставляю свою регулярку то всё нормально работает ( url станет /main/index)
если же url /main/index и моя регулярка то url станет /maindex
мне нужно чтобы он нашёл именно первые два символа ( если они есть ) а дальше я их просто удаляю через replace функцию

Comment: 1) https://regex101.com 2) примеры сток 3) что-то мне подсказывает, что достаточно ```let o = { ru: null, en: null }; let url = `/qwa/ru/qwa-qwa/`.split('/').filter(str => !(str in o)).join('/');console.log(url)```